# How to remove the first letter in each cell in a column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column in excel like below,

```
'04-Feb-01
'04-Mar-01
'08-Apr-01
'06-May-01
'03-Jun-01
'08-Jul-01
'05-Aug-01
```

I want to remove the character `'` in all cells how can i do that?

I already tried with `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)`  this one.. not working

Comment: I tried your formula and it worked for me using all of the example values you provided.  What results are you getting with your formula?

Comment: Try doing a Data \ Text to Columns. This should remove the opening ' and convert your data to dates. You can then format your column as dd-mmm-yy

Comment: @Aaron Hawkins i Forgot to mention one thing in excel the date values looks like 04-Feb-01 when click the cell it shows like '04-Feb-01 this. is that problem?

Comment: @nutsch yes you are right. the ' symbol is gone.but i change that columns to date type (YYYY-MM-DD) again ' adds to column.

Comment: 1) Do you see a little green corner in the top of each cell?  2) After converting the cell to text and selecting the cell, what value do you see in the formula bar?

Comment: How do you "change that columns to date type (YYYY-MM-DD)"? Change the format or convert back to text? Do you need the column to be text?

Comment: Can you not use the replace function to remove the ' symbol.  Under the home tab>>Find>>replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the text to a date using DATEVALUE.  Then apply a date format to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter data into a cell, Excel will try and convert it to the correct type (is it text, a number or a date) The single quote is Excel's way of saying treat what follows as text. It comes in handy when entering things like telephone numbers which Excel might think is a number and would not display leading zeros. In your the example the actual value in the cell is the text without the single quote, you can check this by copying a cell and then pasting into notepad and there would be no quote in the result.

Why do you want to remove the quote? If it is because you want the cells to contain a date rather than text you can convert it using the DATEVALUE function or by using copy and paste special values only .